# Runtime Error when trying to access a stack containing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stl, stack

Im trying to reverse the nodes in a linked list between two given indexes im using a stack to do this its holding all the relevant nodes but i cant access the nodes im getting a runtime error with this specific line

p.first->next = s.top();

```
    /**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * struct ListNode {
     *     int val;
     *     ListNode *next;
     *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
     * };
    */
    using namespace std;
    #include <stack>
    #include <pair>
    class Solution {
    public:
         ListNode* reverseBetween(ListNode* head, int m, int n) {
         ListNode* nd = head;
         int count = 0;
         stack<ListNode*> s;
         pair<ListNode*, ListNode*> p;
        while(nd->next != NULL){
            count ++;
            if(count = m-1){
                p.first = nd;
            }
            if(count >= m and count <= n){
                s.push(nd);
            }

            if(count = n+1){
                p.second = nd;
            }
            nd=nd->next;
        }

        (p.first)->next = s.top()
        ListNode* temp =s.top();
        s.pop();
        /*
        while(!s.empty()){
            temp->next = s.top();
            s.pop();
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = p.second;
        */
        return head;
    }
};
```

Comment: "this specific line" is a completely meaningless statement. Just because a program crashes on one particular line doesn't mean that's where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere, which is why stackoverflow.com's [help] tells you that you must meet all the requirements for a [mcve], that anyone can use to reproduce your problem. Otherwise it's unlikely that your question will be answerable.

Comment: i only get the runtime error with that specific like un commented

Comment: the runtime error occurs when i try to set the nodes next pointed to stack.top()

Comment: And, I repeat, that means absolutely nothing. It would only take me a few minutes to write a contrived example where adding or removing a line of code makes the program crash because some other completely unrelated function didn't use a pointer properly, and corrupted memory. I repeat: C++ does not work this way. Your question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], and it's unlikely that anyone can tell you why it's crashing, until it does.

Comment: [mcve] or no deal.

Comment: `if(count = m-1){` should likely be `if(count == m-1){`. `=` is assignment, `==` is equality comparison.

Comment: figured it out really stupid mistake

Comment: yeah thanks i just realized that

Comment: So, what exactly did this have to do with the specific line that was crashing?  Nothing. Now you see how C++ works?

Comment: Also `if(count = n+1){` should probably be `if(count == n+1){`